# Firebase: Authentication using Google, Where must I obtain the id_token?

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication

In the Firebase unity3D SDK When I try to obtain the credential it ask me for an **id_token** and an **access_token** .

I have guess that access_token must be null for some examples I have seen, but I have no idea of what to do with this id_token. Code example:

This is the call:

```
Firebase.Auth.GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(string id_token,string access_token);
```

This is an unity3D example code:

```
public void GoogleLogin(Action<bool> loginOK)
{
    string id_token = "90096201****-353hvgf63fecvvc3mi****s6140f98a.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    Firebase.Auth.Credential credential;
    credential = Firebase.Auth.GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(id_token,null);
    auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith (task => 
    {
        if (!task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted)
        {
            loginOK(true);
        }
        else
        {
            loginOK(false);
        }

        if (task.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogException(task.Exception);
        }
    });
}
```

I thought it would be the Oauth 2.0 token which comes from from the google console. But this seems to not be working . Google answer is telling me the next:

> 11-29
>   13:58:25.476  com.google.android.gms  2009    3225    I   AuthChimeraService
>   "message": "**Unable to parse Google id_token**:
>   90096201****-353hvgf63fecvvc3mi****s6140f98a.apps.googleusercontent.com"

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I'm not too fond of building a bridge between Android and Unity if it's not absolutely necessary, neither do I want to use 3rd party plug-ins.

Comment: I am also stuck in the same problem. Did you figure this one out yet?

Answer (score 1):

The [firebase sample for google sign in in unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/google-signin) should help you with this. One of the first steps mentions:

> Follow instructions for [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin#authenticate_with_firebase) and [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin#2_implement_google_sign-in) to get an ID token for the Google sign in.

The firebase documentation also has a subsection for [manually verifying id tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) but they do advice against this.

Comment: The example doesn't show how to obtain the idtoken from Unity3D. Also their docs are outdated.

Comment: @MX D There is not enough documentation to provide the explanation on as where can I get the string id_token,string access_token.

I have an empty project with FirebaseAuth.unitypackage imported.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a Oauth 2.0 token that is required here,

for that you can use this.

n you can't provide your own token as it may change with respect to user.

```
private void getGoogleOAuthTokenAndLogin() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
   // Log.e("SahajLOG", "Login PREF ISSSSSSSS ONCREATE  "+prefs.getBoolean("AuthByGplus", AuthByGplus));
    if (!prefs.getBoolean("AuthByGplus", AuthByGplus)) {
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            String errorMessage = null;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String token = null;

                try {
                    String scope = String.format("oauth2:%s", Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN);
                    token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(MainActivity.this, Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient), scope);
                } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                /* Network or server error */
                    Log.e("SahajLOG", "Error authenticating with Google: " + transientEx);
                    errorMessage = "Network error: " + transientEx.getMessage();
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                    Log.w("SahajLOG", "Recoverable Google OAuth error: " + e.toString());
                /* We probably need to ask for permissions, so start the intent if there is none pending */
                    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
                        mIntentInProgress = true;
                        Intent recover = e.getIntent();
                        startActivityForResult(recover, MainActivity.GOOGLE_SIGIN);
                    }
                } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                /* The call is not ever expected to succeed assuming you have already verified that
                 * Google Play services is installed. */
                    Log.e("SahajLOG", "Error authenticating with Google: " + authEx.getMessage(), authEx);
                    errorMessage = "Error authenticating with Google: " + authEx.getMessage();
                }

                return token;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
                mGoogleLoginClicked = false;
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                if (token != null) {
                    Log.e("SahajLOG", "TOKEN IS  " + token);
               //     firebaseAuthWithGoogle(token);


                    //onGoogleLoginWithToken(token);
                    resultIntent.putExtra("oauth_token", token);
                } else if (errorMessage != null) {
                    resultIntent.putExtra("error", errorMessage);
                }
                setResult(MainActivity.GOOGLE_SIGIN, resultIntent);
                finish();
            }
        };
        task.execute();
    }
    Log.e("SahajLOG", "oAuthCalled");
    /* Get OAuth token in Background */
}
```

Comment: Remember that I'm using Unity3D . It's supposed that I must do it from unity.

Comment: Have you tried **Google Play Games plugin for Unity**

Comment: The question is, Must I use another thirdparty to obtain the credential for Firebase?

Comment: Firebase only wants is the token id so that they can use it to authenticate the person, So yes you can use 3rd party

Comment: I know I can use it. But Is that the only way? Can I provide a random Id?

Comment: No, actually id send by you to firebase is again checked by google server and then it authenticate the user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Google Sign in SDK for unity to sign in with google first, after singed, you will get id_token to auth with Firebase.